# How to validate Linq join query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying construct a linq method where I can validate two parameters using join and where clauses, but currently I am getting an compiling error - Cannot use local variable 'query' before it is declared -- error.

```
 public bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        var query = from t in db.Trial_Try
                    join u in db.UserDetails on t.tUID equals u.uID
                    where t.tExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                    t.tPublication.Value == 163 &&
                    u.uUsername == username &&
                    u.uPassword == password
                   select query.FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
var query = (from t in db.Trial_Try
                join u in db.UserDetails on t.tUID equals u.uID
                where t.tExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                t.tPublication.Value == 163 &&
                u.uUsername == username &&
                u.uPassword == password
               select t) .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or u if you wan't those values

Basically you are trying to use query in your select clause, which is not what it is expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry to inform but the above solution gave me -- does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'ER_Feb_2014.Trial_Try' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) -- error.  So, I updated the code by adding a return statement and manage to get it to work.  Thank you for your help and solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from t in db.Trial_Try
                    join u in db.UserDetails on t.tUID equals u.uID
                    where t.tExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                    t.tPublication.Value == 163 &&
                    u.uUsername == username &&
                    u.uPassword == password
                   select t.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {

        var query = from t in db.Trial_Try
                    join u in db.UserDetails on t.tUID equals u.uID
                    where t.tExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                    t.tPublication.Value == 163 &&
                    u.uUsername == username &&
                    u.uPassword == password
                    select u; 

        // "execute" the query
        return query.FirstOrDefault() != null; 

    }
```